# poll within the email with mailchimp or campaign monitor, without redirect

Tags: email, html-email, mailchimp, surveymonkey, campaign-monitor

Is it possible make a poll - survey directly within the email?
for example: the user receive this email with a poll inside, he click one of the answers and the system take his vote.
so the voting takes place within the email and doesn’t redirect to another page.
I would like to use or mailchimp or campaign monitor, I know that there is some tools that can make this job, but I don't know if it is possible register the vote without a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even MailChimp [says](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/send-a-survey) that trying to poll entirely within the email is a bad idea. They have some simple tools to ask a single question in an email, but those also take users to an external web page too.